# Having trouble showing following geometric series has closed form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

So the problem lies in the indices of the summation, they go from $n=-(N-1)$ to $n=-1$.

So need to show that $\sum_{n=-(N-1)}^{-1}\omega^n=\frac{\omega^{-(N-1)}-1}{1-\omega}$.

I tried the following and yielded, $\sum_{n=-(N-1)}^{-1}\omega^n=\omega^{-(N-1)}+\omega^{-(N-2)}+...+\omega^{-1}=\omega^{-1}+...+\omega^{-(N-2)}+\omega^{-(N-1)}=\omega^{-1}(1+...+\omega^{-(N-1)}+\omega^{-N})=\omega^{-1}\frac{1-\omega^{-(N-1)}}{1-\omega}=\frac{\omega^{-1}-\omega^{-N}}{1-\omega}$

This is obviously wrong.
Any advice would help

Comment: 1) Check the last power when you factor. 2) Check the denominator.

Comment: ok, now I see it. It took me awhile to see what you were saying, thanks!